# #region in XAML

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I actually don't like #region in my code. *BUT* for some reason call me crazy, I would like to have them in my XAML. I would like whole sections to have a #region-like thing and collapse them (e.g. my <Window.CommandBindings>, <Grid.*Definitions>, <Menu>, <Toolbar>, etc..

Does this exist? If not, how about <RegionCollapse>

Comment: I like the idea, but I don't think there's anything like it... however you can collapse any XAML element ;)

Comment: if it's still relevant 

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c534623-bb05-417f-afc0-c9e26bf0e177

please post if you found out a shortcut like ctrl+m o which collapses all the region and nodes

Answer (score 175, accepted):

OP NOTE: [this was the original right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888407/3225) and in some ways still is a good and for some best answer including me. BUT this answers the original question best I think.

Visual Studio 2015 finally adds support for regions in XAML. You enclose your *regional* code like this:

```
<!--#region RegionName-->

All Your XAML In Here

<!--#endregion-->
```

This will add a collapse icon to the left of starting line, using which you can expand/collapse the region.

Don't know how handy this would practically be since we can already collapse/expand any node in XAML editor. It's there anyway if you want to use.

Comment: I think it could become handy if for example I have multiple controls of the same nature that I want to group, or if I want to group resources by type (images, styles, etc.), etc...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for anybody using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: My use case comes from VS2013, and for me, sometimes I have to comment out large regions of XAML that are temporarily being set aside, and I don't want to have to scroll through all of the text in the editor.  I probably could have stuck everything inside of another XAML element, but I like the new #region feature.

Comment: After some fiddling, I noticed a minor caveat to this solution: The labels are space-sensitive. That is, you must write `<!--#region Name-->`, NOT `<!-- #region Name-->` (note the extra space). This applies to both the starting and ending labels. I'm running VS2015 Professional.

Comment: Not working for me in Visual Studio 2017. I'm aware of the label being space-sensitive.

Comment: @webo80: Can you post you XAML or any reproducible example? I have VS2017 on my machine and it seems to work ok.

Comment: Just note this only seems to works for WPF apps today, UWP isn't supported.

Comment: I would add there is a risk as collapsed region look just like a a bit of grey text with border and with the expand plus icon, it is not very visible that something important e.g. code, is hidden there

Answer (score 53):

I wrote [a Visual Studio Extension to do this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c534623-bb05-417f-afc0-c9e26bf0e177).

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try it out when I get back to a Silverlight/WPF.

Comment: Jacob, your extension is superb!

Comment: Superb! The VS team should just integrate this. Thanks!

Comment: Not bad, but both your solution and Microsoft's solution have the same problem for me. I want to be able to ignore an entire region by putting my ignore namespace `c:` at the beginning of the region tag. This won't work if the region tag is a comment.

Answer (score 22):

I might be missing the point of your request, but the XAML editor automatically puts collapsible regions around the elements.  Note the nodes in the left rail of the editor window.  Click the "-" and the associated element collapses to a single line, much like a #region.

Comment: +1, and you can put XML comments in with the XAML to "header" the sections.

Comment: I know about that, but when I open the file, I need actively do it I'm looking for it to be automatic on file open.

Comment: Yeah, no problem.  Edit + Outlining + Toggle.  It will restore the state when you load the project again, making it "automatic".

Comment: Can you auto-collapse the elements? Like CTRL+M+O for XAML?

Comment: I am also looking for "Collapse to Definition" keyboard shortcut for XAML

Comment: I use CTRL+M+L once or twice to collapse everything, then expand the root element. Or just use the Document Outline to see a simpler view of the xaml.

Comment: Future users: Read more answers, it is possible to date with vs 2015 (built-in) or an extension.

Answer (score 9):

No, but according to [this reply](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/338479/concept-of-region-endregion-for-xaml) by Microsoft:

> This is a great suggestion. Thanks very much. We will consider it for a future release

Comment: And here we are in 2015 ... *sigh*

Comment: @TheEye has anything changed 2 eons later (2017)?

Comment: didn't work with XAML for the last 2 years, sorry - happily back to Swift :-)

Answer (score 4):

FYI: This one has been updated to work well with VS 2012
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c534623-bb05-417f-afc0-c9e26bf0e177

And this VS2012 extension does a nice job of beautifying the XAML so attributes automatically sort and align etc.
http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2012 Update 4, I was able to select a very large section of XAML code, right click and choose "hide selection".  (basically collapses that section with the [...] notation, and after expanding it, the system "remembers" that I wanted to collapse that portion with the [-] notation next to the line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can add comments to the XAML file using SSI formatting:

```
<!-- Grid Styles -->
<style...>
<style...>

<!-- Window Styles -->
<style...>
<style...>
<style...>
```

This at least gives you some sort of "header" if you use the built-in XML collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

VS2010 will remember the collapsed areas but beware this stopped working when I applied SP1 (as did a lot of other things). After uninstalling VS2010 (and any extensions) and doing the following install procedure the XAML elements that were collapsed seemed to be remembered fine:

- Install VS2010 (Pro in my case)
- Install VS2010 windows updates (including an XML editor one, 200MB+)
- Install SP1 Install
- Install VS2010 SP1 windows updates

Might help someone.