# is there WPF XAML regions?

Tags: wpf, xaml, regions

When I have some blocks I want to collapse like that:

```
<region 123>
</region>
```

is there something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [#region in XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888347/region-in-xaml)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33339086/5395773

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at this. it is VS 2010 extension.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c534623-bb05-417f-afc0-c9e26bf0e177

Answer (score 1):

There's no real support for user-defined code folding in XAML. Most IDEs, like VS support code folding on XAML tags like this:

```
-|      <UserControl>
+|          <Grid[...]>
-|      <UserControl/>
```

Although code folding is something I'd usually [avoid in general](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/the-problem-with-code-folding.html)

Also, duplicate of [#region in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888347/region-in-xaml).

Comment: The link provided about avoiding regions only points out disadvantages of region and is more about abusing them than using them. [Do you say No to C# Regions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755465/do-you-say-no-to-c-sharp-regions)