# WPF resourcedictionary organising

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

C# has the #region directive to group methods/properties and collapse them when you aren't working on them to tidy up the visual display area and find what you're looking for easier.

Is there a similar thing you can do in a resource dictionary XAML file?

Comment: I found it as first search result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888347/region-in-xaml. Have you checked it ?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888347/region-in-xaml

Answer (score 2):

In XAML files, you can't create regions but each opening tag can be collapsed only if it has a closing tag like this

```
<Style>
    .....
</Style>
```

Not when you have

```
<Style ..... />
```

These kinds of tags cannot be collapsed.

However there is a VS Extension for doing what you are asking and that can be downloaded from here [XAML Regions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c534623-bb05-417f-afc0-c9e26bf0e177)

For more read this [#region in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888347/region-in-xaml)